# Vue // How to point to assets folder from js method?

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, markerclusterer

I have a vue project generated by vue-cli v3 and I'm trying to provide custom markers for markerclustererplus v3, but it won't work!

I've placed "m" folder containing all m{1-5}.png images and provided imagePath option to MarkerClusterer `imagePath: "/assets/m/m"` but all I get is icon representing failed image loading. Icons have a path that seems to be correct, `http://localhost:8080/assets/m/m2.png`

So far I've tried to move "m" folder to `public` and `components` folder, but it doesn't work either. It also doesn't help if I open `http://localhost:8080/assets/m` folder or files in it from the browser address bar. I also do not see any images at the source tab of the browser.

**UPDATE:**

According to [markerclustererplus](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html#MarkerClustererOptions) documentation `imagePath` property is a string which is:

> The full URL of the root name of the group of image files to use for cluster icons. The complete file name is of the form imagePathn.imageExtension where n is the image file number (1, 2, etc.). The default value is MarkerClusterer.IMAGE_PATH.

So I can't just use require('/folder_path/'), because I'm not calling exact .png that is needed for certain Cluster type and I can't pass Array of images to `imagePath` property, because it's a string.

Here's my `src` directory tree:

```
.
├── App.vue
├── api.js
├── assets
│   ├── logo.png
│   └── m
│       ├── m1.png
│       ├── m2.png
│       ├── m3.png
│       ├── m4.png
│       └── m5.png
├── components
│   ├── google-map.vue
│   └── side-bar.vue
├── dummyData.js
└── main.js
```

I'm passing `imagePath: "/assets/m/m"` option to MarkerClusterer in `google-map.vue` file, it results in `<img src="/assets/m/m2.png">` element in browser.

Comment: Can you show us your project structure? To see how your folders are organized. The problem is in your path, probably.

Comment: @MiguelCruz I've updated the question. Check it out, please

Comment: Same error here...

Answer (score 0):

To refer file from assets folder use @. Your image path, should look like this:

```
<img src="@/assets/m/m2.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that worked for me is to put the images in a folder in the `/public` directory, then set the `imagePath` to that folder. So you'd have:

```
public
  map-cluster-images
    m1.png
    m2.png
    m3.png 
    .....
```

And then when you initiate the `MarkerClusterer`:

```
imagePath: '/map-cluster-images/m'
```